# Change a single marker of extjs chart

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs, charts, extjs4.2

I have an extjs line chart and my markerconfig is circle but at some point I want to change it with a different marker shape like a line or a cross. How I can change a shape for a single marker dynamically and keep rest marker as they are ? I know that we could change attribute properties of a marker but here I want to change the shape.

Comment: do you have the marker connected with lines?

Comment: Yes .. you meant series right ?

Comment: The only option i have in mind id to create three series... disable at the main series your marker (showMarkers: false) (the series is only for the line). Then add another series with all points except the one you want with another marker config. And add a third one with only the one point where u want your sepcial marker cfg. disable the line at series #2 and #3. There could be a better solution though- haha.

Comment: My chart code is generic and it is in use at multiple locations. I think that suggested change will increase complexity.